# Create a JSON array and JSON object

Tags: json, go

I am developing an app for Go. the app is getting JSON data back from a third party.

I do not see how to create the json object and append it to a json array. What's happening is that I have a loop and each element received.

below is the code:

```
type PastWeekWeatherArray struct {
    PastWeekWeather []PastDayWeather `json:"array"`
}

type PastDayWeather struct {
    DayWeather string `json:"day"`
}

func get_weather(ctx context.Context, place string, date string) (string, error){
var msg PastWeekWeatherArray

client := darksky.New(apiKey)

for j:= 0; j < 7; j++ {
    forecast, err := client.get_data(j)
    if(err != nil) {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return "",err
    }
    // forecast.Daily
}
```

the data is contained in the forecast.Daily. this response need to be stored in 'PastDayWeather', json obect and then append to the PastWeekWeatherArray

`forecast.Daily` is returning a (type *Datablock), I would like to cast it or make it a JSON and then insert in the JSON Array.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks. Are you not using PastDayWeather ? and also forecast.Daily is a (type *Datablock). Is there a way to cast to a JSON or PastDayWeather? Sorry I am newby  to golang

Comment: @CeriseLimón added the return type for forecast.Daily

Comment: what is the structure of forecast.Daily, you need to use json Unmarshal

Answer (score 1):

if I understood right the code below can help you.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type PastWeekWeatherArray struct {
    PastWeekWeather []PastDayWeather `json:"pastWeekWeather"`
}

type PastDayWeather struct {
    DayWeather string `json:"dayWeather"`
}

var (
    jsonTest = `{
        "pastWeekWeather": [
            {"dayWeather":"10"},
            {"dayWeather":"15"}
        ]   
    }`
)

func main() {
    array := PastWeekWeatherArray{make([]PastDayWeather, 0)}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonTest), &array)

    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)

    for _, v := range array.PastWeekWeather{
        fmt.Println("Day: ", v.DayWeather)
    }
}
```

Pay attention that the tag json like `json:"pastWeekWeather"` needs to have the same name that I put in the variable name in jsonTest. 
Also you can run the code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/DjtRAVfLJ_)

Comment: you are right, the only things is that I have to build the jsonTest. What I have  a method called 'weather' let's say and I get the information from weather by doing weather.temperature.

Comment: I have to fill the jsonTest field value using the weather method